# SQL Select the highest sale for the current month

Tags: sql

I am trying to Select the name, email address that has the highest individual sale for the current month but for some reason my select statement won't return the right date or the highest amount. Any guidance or help on right direction would be appreciated

```
Select 
    FirstName, LastName,Email, SaleDate, Max(Total)as HighestTotal
From 
    Sale, Employee
where 
    month(SaleDate) = 12    
Group by 
    SaleDate, FirstName, LastName, Email
```

Comment: What is in your table ?
What do you want as a result ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: See, you didn't specify dbms, and now you got at least two product specific answers (for different products...) Save yourself and others some time, tag properly in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY HighestTotal desc` to get the highest individual `sale` for the given `month`

Also use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax to join two tables. Considering that both the tables have `emp_id` as common column

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties E.FirstName,
                       E.LastName,
                       E.Email,
                       S.SaleDate,
                       S.Total AS HighestTotal
FROM   Sale S
       INNER JOIN Employee E
               ON E.emp_id = S.Emp_id
WHERE  Month(S.SaleDate) = 12
ORDER  BY HighestTotal DESC
```

`With Ties` will bring more than one employee in case of tie in highest individual `sale`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to add a condition for the current year:

where month( SaleDate) = 12 AND year(SaleDate) = 2015

2) You have to add ORDER BY to get the highest value:

```
ORDER BY HighestTotal DESC
LIMIT 1
```